# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'mid'

Tags: python, numpy, huggingface-transformers, summarization, huggingface

While implementing this code for [mt5 summarization of hugging face](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/5#finetuning-mt5-with-the-trainer-api)
This error occurred : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15M1w.png)

```
18     )
     19     # Extract the median scores
---> 20     result = {key: value.mid.fmeasure * 100 for key, value in result.items()}
     21     return {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'mid'
```

Is there something I could do? since the code is kinda fixed.
Thank you :)

Comment: Apparently that code did not expect to receive a `float64` object as the `value`. It expected an object which has the `mid` attribute.

Comment: Running code that you don't understand, and that none of us are familiar with, is hard.  You have to follow the documented requirements of that code carefully.  Apparently `result` is a `dict`, and the code expects the values to be some sort of object that has a `mid` attribute.  But you have, some how, created one that contains numbers.  `mid` is not an attribute of any `numpy` object, array or otherwise.  It must be something unique to that `huggingface` code.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj suggests, this is a "Hugging Face" thing.

As for example explained in Hugging Face's YouTube video ["What is the ROUGE metric?"](https://youtu.be/TMshhnrEXlg) at 3:20 which is linked from the tutorial you cite, the call to `compute` of a metric loaded via `load_metric` used to (?) return a more complex data structure (including confidence intervals for the metrics) than what `evaluate` does now. The `mid` then extracts/extracted the "median" confidence interval.

Now, just using `value` instead of `value.mid.fmeasure` does the trick:

```
result = {key: value * 100 for key, value in result.items()}
```